# Returning with a Local Variable in a Function Template

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, lifetime

In the example below the function template is returning with a local variable and it works as expected even though the return value is not a reference. Is there a lifetime extension scenario in here? "result" variable is a local one and compiler doesn't generate any messages, and the code works as well. I expect that it fails since a local variable is used in the return statatement but it works.

```
template <typename F>
auto foo(const F& f)
{
    return [f](const std::vector<double>& v)
    {
        std::vector<double> result(v.size());
        std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), result.begin(), f);
        return result;
    };
}
```

Comment: *"the function template is returning with a local variable"* -- No, the template returns a function object (the lambda). The *lambda* returns a local variable.

Comment: Hmm... why a function template instead of a function? How does the question implode if you remove that complication? (E.g., `auto foo(const std::function<double(double)>& f)`) ... Also, why a lambda? What difference do you see between this scenario and something like `auto foo() { std::vector<double> result(20, 5.0); return result; }`? This simplified example matches your textual description in that it returns a local variable. What is the complication you see in your example? This could be good information to have in the question for future visitors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a lifetime extension scenario in here?

No, not at all. The function returns a capture-by-value lambda (with no references to local variables). It carries its own data and is therefore 100% safe when it comes to lifetimes.

> "result" variable is a local one

It won't even exist until the call operator of the returned lambda is invoked. It will then be a local variable - most probably elided out of existence by *Named Return Value Optimization*.

> How does it store the result variable?

Exactly like as-if you created a local class with a member, instantiated it and returned the instance:

```cpp
struct my_lambda {
    std::vector<double> operator()(const std::vector<double>& v) const {
        std::vector<double> result(v.size());
        std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), result.begin(), f);
        return result;
    }
    F f;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it now. Sorry for the confusion. In my understanding, the lambda only has f (from capture) and v from the parameter. How does it store the result variable?

Comment: @terto You're welcome. I answered in the answer.